# Difference between "isoaspartyl" and "isoaspartate" in antibody deamidation

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, terminology

I'm translating a text where antibody [deamidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deamidation) is mentioned.

One sentence goes like this:

> We used reversed-phase HPLC to analyze the **aspartyl** forms of the monoclonal antibody. (Russian original text: "изоаспартильные формы")

However, [in scientific papers the word is "isoaspartate", not "isoaspartyl"](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4010776/).  (also [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12467919))

On the other hand, Wikipedia's page "[Isoaspartate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoaspartate)" changes the term mid-flight to "isoaspartyl":

> **Isoaspartyl** formation reactions have been conjectured to be one of the factors that limit the useful lifetime of proteins.
>
> **Isoaspartyl** formation proceeds much more quickly if the asparagine is followed by a small, flexible residue (such as Gly) that leaves the peptide group open for attack. These reactions also proceed much more quickly at elevated pH (>10) and temperatures.

I'm perplexed. Are the forms of an aged antibody "isoaspartate forms" or "isoaspartyl forms"?  What is the exact difference between "isoaspartate" and "isoaspartyl", and why the Wiki page makes no mention of the difference?

Comment: I think a IUPAC literate chemist will give the right answer, but shortly: it's not as complicated as you think it is. -yl endings are commonly used to refer to a (side)group, in this case of the aspartate residue. Similar to a phenyl or isopropyl group in organic chemistry.